# Exclude address from "send from" list

Tags: bitcoind

When we use `send` or `sendtoaddress` methods we can't control directly from which addresses of the node it will be collected. Is there any way to exclude particular address, so node will never use it as a source of BTC? And opposite sometimes I need to send only from the particular address